# Setting Expires/Caching headers in a Web API Formatter

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Is is possible to set the expiration/caching headers inside of a MediaTypeFormatter in Web API?  I have tried overriding the SetDefaultContentHeaders and setting the expires header like so:

```
public override void SetDefaultContentHeaders(Type type, System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpContentHeaders headers, System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue mediaType)
    {            
       headers.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(24);            
    }
```

But the expires header always comes back with -1 when viewing it in a web debugger like the Chrome tools.  It also doesn't appear that setting the CacheControl header is not possible here as that is a response header and not a content header (whatever that means).

Comment: Same question here with a workaround but still no answers... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14361219/setting-http-expires-header-in-mediatypeformatter-setdefaultcontentheaders-has-n

Answer (score 9):

Seems any setting of `HttpResponseMessage.Headers.CacheControl` causes the Expires header to be emitted as set, but without it set Expires is emitted with a value of -1.  Try setting `response.Headers.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue()` but *without setting max-age*.  You should be able to do this anywhere that exposes `HttpResponseMessage`; e.g. in the `ApiController` or a `DelegatingHandler`.

As per [RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.3), if CacheControl's max-age is present, it overrides Expires, but if you just set it as above it should work.

Whether or not this is a good idea is debatable, as Expires is HTTP 1.0, while CacheControl is HTTP 1.1.

Comment: Blame the hosting layer.  If you use Self-Host or Owin host, you will never see that non-http-compliant `Expires: -1`

Answer (score 0):

You should set a corresponding cache control header in the output HttpResponse object that defines an expiration time. Unfortunately WebAPI does not have a built-in support out of the box but luckily it's not difficult to implement. For an example take a look here: http://blog.turlov.com/2013/11/setting-cache-control-http-headers-in.html